# Optional attributes in a macro wrapping a Java Ant Task

Tags: ant, macros, attributes, macrodef

Ant tasks implemented in Java, as opposed to XML Ant macros, have this peculiarity of offering a slightly different behavior for missing attributes.

In my case, I'm trying to wrap the `<testng>` Ant task, implemented in Java, with a macro.  Specifically, I would like to expose most of the functionality offered by the TestNG ant task with some minor tweaks.

Among other similar attributes, `timeOut` seems a bit difficult to reproduce, since its omission behaves differently than specifying and empty string.

This is simplified version of my macro definition:

```xml
<macrodef name="my-wrapper">
  <attribute name="timeOut" default=""/>
  <element name="nested-elements" optional="true" implicit="true"/>
  <sequential>
    <testng timeOut="@{timeOut}">
      <nested-elements/>
    </testng>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Which fails because Ant tries to convert the value to an integer:

```
Can't assign value '' to attribute timeout, reason: class java.lang.NumberFormatException with message 'For input string: ""'
```

I've been suggested to use `<augment>`, which seems to be the solution to this problem.  However, I fail to understand how it should be used:

```xml
<macrodef name="my-wrapper">
  <attribute name="timeOut" default=""/>
  <element name="nested-elements" optional="true" implicit="true"/>
  <sequential>
    <augment unless:blank="timeOut" id="invocation" timeOut="@{timeOut}"/>
    <testng id="invocation">
      <nested-elements/>
    </testng>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

The above fails because of a forward reference:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown reference "invocation"
```

Invering the order of `<testng>` and `<augment>` doesn't really work because the `<testng>` task starts executing before being *augmented*.

What I would need is a way to conditionally add an XML attribute to a task call.  Is this possible only using Ant XML syntax?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, the simplest solution would just be to set the default for `timeOut` to a valid value. It expects a string that can be resolved as an integer, so try using `-1` if you don't want there to be a max timeout.

```
<macrodef name="my-wrapper">
  <attribute name="timeOut" default="-1"/>
  <element name="nested-elements" optional="true" implicit="true"/>
  <sequential>
    <testng timeOut="@{timeOut}">
      <nested-elements/>
    </testng>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Comment: Not really:

https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/67b8f040aae98088cab6331a78d66c9536f87b27/src/main/java/org/testng/TestNGAntTask.java#L854-L867

https://github.com/apache/ant/blob/4df62008f342b6890c1160f6f92c56423738eb4d/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/util/Watchdog.java#L51-L60

Comment: @C2H5OH My bad. That's how most other Ant tasks work, but I guess testng is different. It's a bit hacky but why not just set the default to a really high number? It's a `long` type in the code, so you can make it effectively wait forever.

Comment: It's ok.  We are going to avoid relying on the "timeout" parameter for now.  If the need arises, we will turn the XML macro into a Java task extending from TestNG.